# Windows hello pin removal/crack

Tags: windows, account-security, password-reset

Is there a workaround to the Windows 10 Hello PIN security login policy?

The PIN is the only credential needed to log in, no password is set, checked with samdump2.

I inherited this computer from a recently deceased family member, Microsoft refuses to send us the credentials for privacy reasons.

I dual-booted a Debian distro from which I can read the files on the Windows partition. Funny enough, the Desktop folder is completely empty, which is very strange.

I tried to "crack" the PIN using the WINHELLO2hashcat python script developed by the hashcat team: https://hashcat.net/forum/thread-10461.html
Unfortunately, the TPM is enabled and the script is useless.

1. Is there a way to reset the PIN as it is possible for passwords with the help of Trinity Rescue Kit, for example?
2. Is there any kind of file protection I am not aware of?

Comment: I am a little confused.  You havent even mentioned the normal excuse of `wanting to preserve  photos or documents`.  So, why not just reinstall Windows ?

Comment: Why do you need to log into the account? Since the drive isn't encrypted, you can access all of the files, and even create a new user (by editing the SAM, etc.) if it was necessary. The only things you'd be missing are credentials and other data secured by the user's account password... which, you say, doesn't exist. Are you perhaps trying to get into the OneDrive account? That, unlike the local Windows account, is something Microsoft _might_ be able to help with (the Windows Hello PIN never leaves the device so Microsoft couldn't tell you what it was even if they tried).